# Android keeps rebooting

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, zte-light-tab

I have a ZTE v9. I flashed it with CynogenMod7 from [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=stable&device=v9). I have installed ClockworkMod recovery 4.0.0.2. Then I rebooted phone from recovery. Now, the phone keeps restarting.

I can't get into recovery mode using power + volume down button (earlier I could). I have a backup of previous rom. How can I restore it?

Comment: Any `adb logcat` errors?

Comment: @NoBugs adb devices does not load anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NEVER EVER FLASH ANDROID ROM WITHOUT WIPING DATA / CACHE WIPE DALVIK CACHE
FORMAT SYSTEM (optional, but requires for some rom)*

Always read instructions carefully before flashing any Rom / Mod and reverify whether its for your phone model only.

Anyway, as you said you are not able to go to Recovery mode, therefore there is no use of having a backup. Try to reset your phone, (ie, press power button for approx 7 - 10 sec). If nothing works, follow below instructions:

- Take out the battery. Put on the back cover.
- Hold both <kbd>volume +</kbd> and <kbd>volume -</kbd> while plug in the USB cable to a PC. It will automatically get into FTM mode.
- Then flash generic 2.2 firmware on it.
- After flashing, it may stuck in the FTM loop. Put in the battery and flash again.
- After 2nd flashing, take out the battery for 10 seconds. Then put it back.
- Press and hold both <kbd>Power</kbd> and <kbd>Volume +</kbd> to boot into Android.

I have no experience with ZTE v9, so i can't hand on step by step tutorial . Hope your phone gets well soon.

**Sources:**

- [Modaco: ZTE bricked](http://www.modaco.com/topic/341288-zte-v9-bricked/)
- [AndroidForums: ZTE unbrick manual](http://androidforums.com/general-tablet-talk/634372-optus-zte-v9-un-brick-tutorial.html)